# codeigniter files not working on godaddy windows hosting

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

When I'm trying to acess below url not getting any response:

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php/Admin/index/
```

My codeigniter files present in:

```
http://subdomain.domain.com
```

in my .htacces file:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

in my config.php file:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://subdomain.domain.com/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Comment: "Not getting any response" could mean a variety of things. What exactly does your browser say when you go there? 404? DNS not found?

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

in config you will need to list the domain wit a traling slash and remove the  index.php

```html
$config['base_url'] = "http://subdomain.domain.com/";
$config['index_page'] = "";
$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO";
```

URL to go to if you have an index controller method in your Admin controller the path to it then should be http://subdomain.domain.com/admin/

Controllers and methods described here
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html

Comment: Just realized the question title says "Windows Hosting" .htaccess does not work on windows hosting. https://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig